# Why doesn't \n escape the n character in regex

Tags: regex

Hi there this is a trivial question but why does not \n in strings escape the n character. I am trying to match whitespaces of any length and it got me thinking why \s+ results in an escaped s. Why do we have to escape the backslash unlike \n.

Is there anymore exceptions like the \n where we do not have to escape the backslash?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, `\n` as in a new line character? There are `\t` (tab) and `\r` (carriage-return).

[Maybe take a look at this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)